# Menú desplegable lateral en barra lateral con HTML y CSS puro

Tags: html, css

Estoy haciendo una página HTML con una barra horizontal superior y otra lateral izquierda. La lateral tiene un menú desplegable hacia la derecha.

El problema es cuando intento introducir un `div` entre la barra horizontal y la lateral ya que, si el `div` lo pongo en posición absoluta o relativa el desplegable se oculta tras el `div` y si lo dejo estático no me deja moverlo de su posición.

¿Cómo hago para que se vea el nuevo `div` y que el lateral no se desplace?

Os dejo lo que tengo hecho:

```css
@charset "utf-8";
html,
body,
h1,
h2,
h3,
h4,
h5,
h6,
p,
ol,
ul,
li,
pre,
code,
address,
variable,
form,
fieldset,
blockquote {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  font-size: 100%;
  font-weight: normal;
}

table {
  border-collapse: collapse;
  border-spacing: 0;
}

td,
th,
caption {
  font-weight: normal;
  text-align: left;
}

img,
fieldset {
  border: 0;
}

ol {
  padding-left: 1.4em;
  list-style: decimal;
}

ul {
  padding-left: 1.4em;
  list-style: square;
}

q:before,
q:after {
  content: '';
}


/*Fin reset css*/

body {
  color: black;
  background-image: url("/assets/img/fondo_economy.png");
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: cover;
  margin: 0
}


/*Cabecera*/

.header {
  background-color: #26dabc;
  padding: 10px 20px;
  position: fixed;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  height: 65px;
}

.header a {
  text-decoration: none;
}

.container {
  width: 100%;
  max-width: 1750px;
  min-width: 970px;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

.logo-nav-container {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: space-between;
}

.logo {
  font-family: 'Segoe UI', Tahoma, Geneva, Verdana, sans-serif;
  font-size: xx-large;
  font-weight: 700;
  color: rgba(216, 250, 241, 0.808);
  letter-spacing: 2px;
}

.navigation ul {
  margin: 0 20px;
  padding: 0 10px;
  list-style: none;
}

.navigation ul li {
  display: inline-block;
  font-family: 'Segoe UI', Tahoma, Geneva, Verdana, sans-serif;
  font-size: xx-large;
  font-weight: 700;
  color: rgba(216, 250, 241, 0.808);
  letter-spacing: 2px;
}

.navigation ul li a {
  display: block;
  padding: 0.5rem 1rem;
  color: rgba(216, 250, 241, 0.808);
}

.navigation ul li a:visited {
  color: rgba(216, 250, 241, 0.808);
}

.navigation ul li a:hover {
  color: white;
}

#signout {
  padding: 7px;
  margin: 10px;
  font-weight: 400;
  font-size: 20px;
  color: #26dabc;
  background-color: #ffffff;
  border: 2px solid #26dabc;
  border-radius: 20px;
  width: 100px;
  box-shadow: #4ed6c0 2px 2px 10px rgb(93, 141, 133);
}

#signout:hover {
  color: #ffffff;
  background-color: #26dabc;
  border: 2px solid #ffffff;
}


/*Barra lateral*/

#barra-lateral {
  float: left;
  background-color: #66cccc;
  height: 100%;
  position: fixed;
  width: 255px;
  top: 85px;
}

#barra-lateral ul,
li {
  list-style: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

#barra-lateral ul {
  position: relative;
  z-index: 597;
  float: left;
}

#barra-lateral ul li {
  float: left;
  min-height: 1px;
  line-height: 1em;
  vertical-align: middle;
}

#barra-lateral ul li.hover,
#barra-lateral ul li:hover {
  position: relative;
  z-index: 599;
  cursor: default;
}

#barra-lateral ul ul {
  visibility: hidden;
  position: absolute;
  top: 100%;
  left: 0;
  z-index: 598;
  width: 100%;
}

#barra-lateral ul ul li {
  float: none;
}

#barra-lateral ul li:hover>ul {
  visibility: visible;
}

#barra-lateral ul ul {
  top: 0;
  left: 100%;
}

#barra-lateral ul li {
  float: none;
}

#barra-lateral span,
#barra-lateral a {
  display: inline-block;
  font-family: 'Segoe UI', Tahoma, Geneva, Verdana, sans-serif;
  font-size-adjust: inherit;
  font-weight: 700;
  text-decoration: none;
}

#barra-lateral:after,
#barra-lateral ul:after {
  content: '';
  display: block;
  clear: both;
}

#barra-lateral ul,
#mbarra-lateral li {
  width: 100%;
}

#barra-lateral li {
  background: #66cccc;
}

#barra-lateral li:hover {
  background: #26dabc;
  font-size: 1.2em;
}

#barra-lateral a {
  color: white;
  line-height: 160%;
  padding: 11px 28px 11px 28px;
  width: 253px;
}

#barra-lateral a:hover {
  color: rgba(216, 250, 241, 0.808);
}

#barra-lateral ul ul li {
  background: #66cccc;
}

#barra-lateral ul ul li:hover {
  background: #26dabc;
}

#barra-lateral ul ul li:hover a {
  color: rgba(216, 250, 241, 0.808);
}


/*Cuerpo de la página*/

.contenedor-movimientos {
  background: floralwhite;
  float: initial;
  left: 265px;
}
```

```html
<header class="header">
  <div class="container logo-nav-container">
    <h1 class="logo">Logo</h1>
    <nav class="navigation">
      <ul>
        <li><a href="">Grupo</a> </li>
        <li>-</li>
        <li><a href="">Usuario</a> </li>
      </ul>
    </nav>
    <button id="signout" type="submit">Sign out</button>
  </div>
</header>

<div id="barra-lateral">
  <ul>
    <li class="sub-menu"><a href="">Gestionar grupo</a>
      <ul>
        <li><a href="">Añadir usuario</a></li>
        <li><a href="">Eliminar usuario</a></li>
        <li><a href="">Editar usuario</a></li>
        <li><a href="">Editar grupo</a></li>
      </ul>
    </li>
    <li class="sub-menu"><a href="">Imprimir</a> </li>
    <li class="sub-menu"><a href="">Consultar</a> </li>
  </ul>
</div>

<div class="contenedor">
  <div class="box">
    <header class="cabecera">
      <ul>
        <li>Nombre</li>
        <li>|</li>
        <li></li>
        <li>|</li>
        <li></li>
        <li> |</li>
        <li></li>
        <li></li>
        <li></li>
      </ul>
    </header>

    <div>
      <ul id="datos">
        <li></li>
        <li></li>
        <li></li>
        <li></li>
        <li>icono lapiz</li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Lo quiero hacer con HTML y CSS puro, sin librerías como Bootstrap u otras.